# How do you SAFELY make a flash:notice html_safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example, Say I want to add `&ndash;` in my notice message:

```
. . .
  format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: "Success &ndash; Email sent to: #{@learn_more.email}" }
```

Is it safe?... or is it a security risk to do `notice.html_safe` in my view?

Comment: It's only "unsafe" if malicious XSS can be injected or the page is otherwise changed to work in a subversive manner.

Comment: But how can the page be "changed" by a malicious user??

Comment: Any user data which can be supplied in the notice that is *shared* between users, such that a malicious user can modify the HTML in someone else's browser. Of course, if that is possible then even preventing HTML isn't really a cure - as someone could phish with such a notice.

Answer (score 1):

If `@learn_more.email` comes from a user of your site, then you should sanitize it first.

```
"Success &ndash; Email sent to: #{ERB::Util.h(@learn_more.email)}".html_safe
```

The above calls the [`html_escape`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html#method-c-html_escape) method.

Basically, make sure a string is guaranteed to be non-malicious before marking it as safe. Otherwise, malicious input can make it into your site. Malicious input would be something like a user entering a javascript tag in as their email, or anything like that.

Comment: Interesting.. but wouldn't that js only run on the malicious users browser? It wont persist.. How harmful can it be?

Comment: And by the way `ActionController::Base.helpers.h` throws an error... "private method `h' called for #<ActionView::Base:0x0000010de00070>"

Comment: I've updated the code to use `view_context.h` instead of `ActionController::Base.helpers.h`. Apparently things change :).

Comment: How about `ERB::Util.h`? Update answer as well. Also, sanitizing all user-supplied input is a good practice to be in. In this case there may not be much harm that they can do, but not knowing what they can do is the main reason to do it -- at all times. Maybe someday you add dual-login so an admin can log in under a user's persona, then this flash method fires under the admin's persona and now the user's email contains a script to send himself your session info and he/she can now compromise your credentials. There may be a more imminent threat than this, too, but it's not coming to mind.